# Install Exchange Server over SharePoint on the same server

Tags: 2016

Is it possible to install Exchange server 2016 over SharePoint Server 2016 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a short answer:  Yes it's possible for test or learning purpose, but it's not recommended, So It's preferred to install two separate VMs to host Exchange and SharePoint on separate OS installations.

For more details check success story at [Can be Install Exchange Server  and SharePoint  on the same server without any conflict?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/75a00f2f-89bd-4922-9af2-575dc2f0bd1a/can-be-install-exchange-server-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-on-the-same-server-without-any-conflict?forum=exchange2010)

Also, check some expected issues that may face at

- [Exchange Server 2013 and SharePoint Server 2013 on same Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314996/exchange-server-2013-and-sharepoint-server-2013-on-same-box)
- [Installing Sharepoint on the same server as Exchange and Remote Web Access (IIS – Sharepoint -RWA – OWA Conflicts)](https://davejsteele.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-sharepoint-on-the-same-server-as-exchange-and-remote-desktop-web-access-iis-sharepoint-rdweb-owa-conflicts/)

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will follow your advice to install two separate machines